# What is Private Ubuntu extension in Glade?

Tags: glade

In Glade's TreeView setup dialog, what is the "Private Ubuntu extension" option, and what might my application gain/lose if I enable it?

Ubuntu desktop 18.04.2
Glade 3.22.1 (although this option has been there in many earlier versions)

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same question.

In the documentation we can find :

```
The “ubuntu-almost-fixed-height-mode” property

  “ubuntu-almost-fixed-height-mode” gboolean
Private Ubuntu extension.

Owner: GtkTreeView

Flags: Write

Default value: FALSE
```

Looking for `ubuntu-almost-fixed-height-mode` on google, it seems that this is an extension related to the **ubuntu software center**.

Here for example : https://github.com/mortenpi/ubuntu-software-center/blob/897c3933f5a27b6755cde72bb06329a4bc8b97b8/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/apptreeview.py#L61

Whe can read here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/1.1.18

> softwarecenter/view/appview.py:
> - use "ubuntu-almost-fixed-height-mode" when available
> to speed up the treeview drawing significantly